# Como adicionar uma classe em um link do bootstrap

Tags: jquery, html, css3, bootstrap-3, link

Estou utilizando o **bootstrap** e eu tenho um menu, o que eu queria era que quando clicasse em um link desse menu, exibisse a página e deixasse selecionado no menu a página que o usuário está.

Tentei atribuir uma classe usando a função `.addClass()` quando o usuário clicar no menu, porém quando eu clico até vejo que ele muda de cor, entretanto, quando a página termina de carregar ele perde o efeito.

Meu código **JavaScript** esta assim:

```
 $(document).ready(function() {
        $('a.menu').click(function() {
            $(this).addClass("style");
        });
 });
```

**HTML:**

```
<div id="navbar" class="navbar-collapse collapse bloco-menu">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav ">
        <li><a class="menu" href="index.html">O Evento</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="mensagem-presidente.html">Mensagem da Presidente</a></li>
         <li><a class="menu " href="palestrantes.html">Palestrantes</a></li>
          <li><a class="menu" href="localizacao.html">Local do Evento</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="inscricoes.html">Inscrições</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="#contact">Programação</a></li>
         <li><a class="menu" href="stands.html">Mapa de stands</a></li>
          <li><a class="menu" href="hospedagem.html">Hospedagem</a></li>
        <li><a class="menu" href="comissao-organizadora.html">Comissão Organizadora</a></li>
     </ul>

    </div><!--/.nav-collapse -->
  </div>
</nav>
```

**CSS:**

```
.style{color:red;font-weight:bold}
```

Alguem poderia me ajudar ?

Answer (score 1):

Olá, sugiro voce usar a classe "nav nav-pills" o proprio bootstrap deixa marcado o ultimo item clicado do menu.

Answer (score 0):

Basta ajustar seu JS para remover todas as classes `style`:

```
$('a.menu').click(function() {
  $('a.menu').removeClass("style");
  $(this).addClass("style");
});
```

[Exemplo online](https://fiddle.jshell.net/pcd3ftv2/)

No exemplo acima, alterei o comportamento (`href`) dos links para teste...

EDIT:

Quanto à navegabilidade, você pode atribuir um `id` para cada link... no `$(document).ready(function(){})` de cada página, você coloca um JS pra trigar o estilo:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
      $('a.menu').removeClass("style");
      $("#iddobotao").addClass("style");
});
```

Comment: Mesmo removendo o style , não esta dando certo , alguma coisa esta sobrescrevendo quando a pagina termina de recarregar .

Comment: coloca pra adicionar o style em cada página... :)